# How to get POST to submit email

Tags: php, html, forms

Apologies if this is really easy and i should know this.
So i have been getting a lot of spam to a email address via a contact form on my website, so i have decided to add captcha to the site, i have managed to get the captcha to work in so much as it gives message saying you must tick the captch box etc when you click send (without ticking the box) but when you tick the box you get a successful message, but the email does not deliver.

I will post code below -

php on the contact page -

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $subject = "MY Service call form";
    $subject2 = "Copy of MY Service call form";
    $telephone_number = $_POST['telephone_number'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $element2 = $_POST['element2'];
    $contract = $_POST['contract'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $playerinfo = "\n Name : " . $first_name . "\n address : " . $address .     "\n telephone_number : " . $telephone_number . "\n choice : " . $element2 . "\n     contract : " . $contract . "\n message : " . $message . " " .     $_POST['playerinfo'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" .     $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$playerinfo,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the     message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you     shortly.";
    }?>
```

Here is the html form

```
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="first_name" style="border:2px solid #0072ff;" required><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" style="border:2px solid #0072ff;" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="telephone_number" style="border:2px solid #0072ff;"><br/>
      <input type="text" name="address" style="border:2px solid #0072ff;" required><br>
        <label class="emf-label-desc" for="element2">Service call category</label>


              <input id="element_2_0" name="element2" value="UPVC Frames" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_0">UPVC Frames</label>


              <input id="element_2_1" name="element2" value="Glass" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_1">Glass</label>


              <input id="element_2_2" name="element2" value="Composite Doors" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_2">Composite Doors</label>


              <input id="element_2_3" name="element2" value="UPVC Doors" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_3">UPVC Doors</label>


              <input id="element_2_4" name="element2" value="Conservatory" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_4">Conservatory</label>


              <input id="element_2_5" name="element2" value="Plastics" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_5">Plastics</label>


              <input id="element_2_6" name="element2" value="Other" class="validate[optional]" type="radio" /><label class="padleft-w5" for="element_2_6">Other</label>
               Do you have a Contract Number? if so please enter: <input type="text" name="contract" style="border:2px solid #0072ff;" required><br>
         <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="HIDINGMYSECRETKEY"></div>

 <br><textarea rows="10" name="message" cols="50" style="border:2px solid #0072ff;" required></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my form.php to confirm th captcha

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form, go back and tick the box       to confirm you are not a spammer. <a href="http://www.mgwindows.com/repairs.php">CLICK HERE TO GO BACK</a></h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=HIDINGMYSECRETKEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer !</h2>';
        }else
        {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
?>
```

Again thank you for any help on this, the issue again is once you complete the captcha the email is not being delivered to my services email account.

Comment: Sorry im not sure how to post the code correctly on here.

Comment: is the emailing server functional on your PHP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace your php code with this..

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
        echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form, go back and tick the box       to confirm you are not a spammer. <a href="http://www.mgwindows.com/repairs.php">CLICK HERE TO GO BACK</a></h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Lfsqw8TAAAAAEeldyYfwEhQQuhOXbjBBG0dzPwl&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer !</h2>';
          exit;
        }else
        {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';

            $to = "MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM"; // this is your Email address
            $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            $subject = "MY Service call form";
            $subject2 = "Copy of MY Service call form";
            $telephone_number = $_POST['telephone_number'];
            $address = $_POST['address'];
            $element2 = $_POST['element2'];
            $contract = $_POST['contract'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $playerinfo = "\n Name : " . $first_name . "\n address : " . $address .     "\n telephone_number : " . $telephone_number . "\n choice : " . $element2 . "\n     contract : " . $contract . "\n message : " . $message . " " .     $_POST['playerinfo'];
            $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" .     $_POST['message'];
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
            mail($to,$subject,$playerinfo,$headers);
            mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the     message to the sender
            echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you     shortly.";
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you ever so much, this worked, much appreciated and thank you for the suggestion on fixing my question.

Answer (score 0):

You never submit your form therefore your post values is not getting anywhere you can not do this approach without some ajax or by using this simple jquery script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('input[name=name]').change(function(){
    $('form').submit();
 });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if i got your problem, but if you never send out an email after a sucessful captcha you shoud try to add the first block of code you posted into your captcha code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form, go back and tick the box       to confirm you are not a spammer. <a href="http://www.mgwindows.com/repairs.php">CLICK HERE TO GO BACK</a></h2>';
      exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=HIDINGMYSECRETKEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($response.success==false)
    {
      echo '<h2>You are spammer !</h2>';
    }else
    {
      // add your mail sending code here <------------------
      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>
    }
```